# resignFirstResponder succeeds to hide the keyboard only in some of the cases

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, keyboard, uitextfield

I am using `resignFirstResponder` to hide a number pad, but it works only some of the time in hiding the keyboard: I implemented `backgroundTap` with `[textField resignFirstResponder];` and on a background tap the keyboard is indeed hidden. I also added this line in `viewWillDisappear`, but there it works some of the time. When the user goes back to the window he came from, the keyboard disappears. But when he goes to a new window (not the one he came from), the keyboard doesn't disappear. I checked in debug using the method `isFirstResponder`, and in both cases the text-field is indeed not the first responder anymore (although in one of the cases the keyboard keeps being shown, as said).

The implementation of `viewWillDisappear` is this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

I want to hide the keyboard in both case of viewWillDisappear, because the new window doesn't have the text field that is relevant to this keyboard. It has completely different elements.

The event that pushes another view isn't a button click, but the beginning of editing of a text field. I have three text fields in my view, only one of them displays a keyboard. The other two push another view. This is the code for textFieldDidBeginEditing:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField1.editing == YES)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToView1" sender:self];
     }
    else if (textField2.editing == YES)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToView2" sender:self];
    }

}
```

While the text field that generates keyboard is textField3.

Some ideas on how to make the keyboard disappear in both cases?

Comment: What you want Exactly ?

Comment: I changed the ending of the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Why hide keyborad in `viewWillDisappear`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     if (textField == textField1)
     {
         [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
         //else you can try with this also.
         [textField performSelector:@selector(resignFirstResponder)
                withObject:nil
                afterDelay:0];
         //
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToView1" sender:self];
         return NO;
     }
     else if (textField == textField2)
     {
         [self.view endEditing:YES];
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToView2" sender:self];
         return NO;
     }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Tomer: Your TextField is in Main View or in some other View ?

Comment: The event that pushes another view isn't a button click, but the beginning of editing of a text field. I have three text fields in my view, only one of them displays a keyboard. The other two push another view.

Comment: This is the code for textFieldDidBeginEditing: `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField1.editing == YES)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToView1" sender:self];
     }
    else if (textField2.editing == YES)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToView2" sender:self];
    }
    
}`

Comment: While the text field that generates keyboard is textField3.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it creates another bug: the text inserted into the text field that should be edited, seems not to update (it updates in the simulator view, but the functionality it needs to implement doesn't work now).

Answer (score 0):

with this code checks in view the presence of any textfield and use it to close the keyboard. To adapt based on your needs.

```
for (id elem in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([elem isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        [(UITextField *)elem resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Comment: I adde this code on viewWillDisappear but the keyboard still appears.

Comment: which component you open the keyboard?

Comment: my method implies that the keyboard was opened by a textfield, so if you have other components (such as textview), you must also include those in the control

Comment: I open the keyboard with a textfield.

Comment: - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    
    for (id elem in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([elem isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
            [(UITextField *)elem resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}

Comment: I did it this way in a sample application and I get the result that you would like to have